# CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is asked a lot but its a very broad error so i need some help with how to make my vector3 static.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Grid.GridScan(transform.position);
        }

    }
```

"GridScan" is called from here:

```
 public void GridScan(Vector3 worldposition)
    {
        Debug.Log(GetValue(worldposition));
        if ((GetValue(worldposition)) == 100)
        {
            if (Neighbours(worldposition, 2) < 2)
            {
                SetValue(worldposition, 0);
            }
            if ((Neighbours(worldposition, 2)) > 3) 
            {
                SetValue(worldposition, 0);
            }
        }

        if ((GetValue(worldposition)) == 0)
        {
            if (Neighbours(worldposition, 2) == 3)
            {
                SetValue(worldposition, 100);
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is for the first code and for `Grid.GridScan(Vector3)`. The first code is attached to many game objects as they are created. How do I make the `vector3` (`transform.position`) static?

Comment: Is `Grid` an instance of the class that `GridScan` belongs to?

Comment: `public static void GridScan` ?

Comment: John, Grid is the script that includes the function Gridscan.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the GridScan method is not static, you need to call this on a particular grid. You can add the [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) to make it static.

Alternatively you can make Grid a singleton, which means having a static property pointing to the current grid. In Unity you can also use [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) to search for it in the scene, however this is an expensive operation. It has to go through all objects in the scene to find your script, thats much more expensive than getting a static property.

Comment: The Static modifier won't work because the function GridScan uses other non-static variables and functions that need to remain non-static. Will a singleton work if this is the case?

Comment: Yes, so inside Grid you make a static `Current` grid variable. In the Awake or OnEnable of the grid you assign it, and everywhere else you can use it. This is an acceptable approach for when you have one type of component that you want to use in many different places.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly and I am very new to this so very much appreciated. What kind of variable am i making current (int, float)?

Comment: There are a lot of articles which explain it much better than i can, for example: https://riptutorial.com/unity3d/example/14518/a-simple-singleton-monobehaviour-in-unity-csharp

The static variable is supposed to be the Grid, you use it to get the one grid in your scene. So the type should be Grid.